# Why switchMap does not cancel previous observer?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have method described in component (controller):

```
public requestPassportData(): void {
    const th = this;
    const data = {
      get_scanned_data: true
    };

    Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .switchMap(() => this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data))
      .takeWhile(() => {
        return (
          th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 1 ||
          th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 2 ||
          th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 3
        );
      })
      .subscribe(response => {});
}
```

If to call method `requestPassportData()` five times, it will send each second five request to server. Why switchMap does not cancel last observer?

Comment: Perhaps `takeWhile` restricts  to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because every time you call `requestPassportData()` you'll create a new chain with new `Observable.timer` that has nothing to do with the previous calls.

There are obviously multiple ways to solve this but you can for example do the following:

```
private requestPasswordSubject$ = new Subject();

private requestPassword = this.requestPasswordSubject$
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .switchMap(() => this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data))
    .takeWhile(() => {
      return (
         th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 1 ||
         th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 2 ||
         th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 3
      );
    });
  )
  .subscribe(response => {});

public requestPassportData(): void {
  ...
  this.requestPasswordSubject$.next();
}
```

Actual implementation depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve but hopefully you get the point what is different to what you have now.

Comment: How to pass `th` and `data` inside?

Comment: `requestPasswordSubject$` does not support swithMap

Comment: I tried: ` Observable.of(1)
      .switchMap(() =>
        Observable.timer(0, 1000)
          .switchMap(() => this.requestMethods.requestPassportData(data))
          .takeWhile(() => {
            return (
              th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 1 ||
              th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 2 ||
              th.formRegister.currentForm().index == 3
            );
          })
      )
      .subscribe()}`

Comment: If _requestPasswordSubject$ does not support swithMap_, then try converting that subject into observable. `this.requestPasswordSubject$.asObservable().switchMap()`

Comment: Subject inherits from Observable so all operators available for Observables are available on Subjects as well.