# How can I debounce this Angular 7 async validator that uses combineLatest internally?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I sort of understand that the tools involved in this would be `pipe`, `timer`, `switchMap`, `debounceTime`, `distinctUntilChanged`, and possibly more, but I cannot figure out how to make them work with `combineLatest`.

The following validator gets a comma-separated list of emails, and performs an API call for each of them to check if that email exists in the customers database.

```
import {AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";
import {combineLatest} from "rxjs";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/internal/Observable";

import {UtilityApiService} from "../../services/api/utility-api.service";

/**
 * The email address must exist in the database and belong to a customer.
 * It works both with a single email or a comma separate list of emails. In case of a list, it will only validate
 * as a success if ALL emails belong to a customer.
 * @returns {ValidatorFn}
 * @constructor
 */
export class CustomerEmailCsvValidator {
    public static createValidator(internalApiService: UtilityApiService): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            return new Observable((observer) => {
                if (!control.value) {
                    observer.next(null);
                    return;
                }

                const emails: string[] = control.value.split(",").map(email => email.trim());
                const observables: Observable<boolean>[] = emails.map(email => {
                    return internalApiService.isCustomerEmail(email);
                });

                combineLatest(observables).subscribe((responses: boolean[]) => {
                    if (responses.every(value => value)) {
                        // All emails exist and belong to customers. Therefore no error.
                        observer.next(null);
                    } else {
                        // One or more emails do not exist in the database, or do not belong to a customer.
                        // This is an error for this validator.
                        observer.next({customerEmail: true});
                    }
                    observer.complete();
                });
            });
        };
    }
}
```

How can I debounce so that it doesn't run the API calls more than once in 750 ms?

Comment: Use the same approach as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619503/why-switchmap-does-not-cancel-previous-observer/53619577#53619577

Comment: side note, we have similar issues but we remove browser side validation and use autocomplete to let user select email from the list. The server will do actual validation, but nothing happens on client side

Comment: @martin could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to avoid flooding the server with the front calls ?

Comment: You want to create 750ms delays between `internalApiService.isCustomerEmail(email)` calls or debounce just calling the validator function?

Comment: @martin the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
import {AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";
import {combineLatest, of, timer} from "rxjs";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import {map, switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";

import {UtilityApiService} from "../../services/api/utility-api.service";

/**
 * The email address must exist in the database and belong to a customer.
 * It works both with a single email or a comma separated list of emails. In case of a list, it will only validate
 * as a success if ALL emails belong to a customer.
 * @returns {ValidatorFn}
 * @constructor
 */
export class CustomerEmailCsvValidator {
    public static createValidator(internalApiService: UtilityApiService): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            return timer(750).pipe(switchMap(() => {
                if (!control.value) {
                    return null;
                }

                const emails: string[] = control.value.split(",").map(email => email.trim());
                const observables: Observable<boolean>[] = emails.map(email => {
                    return internalApiService.isCustomerEmail(email);
                });

                return combineLatest(observables).pipe(map((responses: boolean[]) => {
                    if (responses.every(value => value)) {
                        // All emails exist and belong to customers. Therefore no error.
                       return null;
                    } else {
                        // One or more emails do not exist in the database, or do not belong to a customer.
                        // This is an error for this validator.
                        return {customerEmail: true};
                    }
                }));
            }));
        };
    }
}
```