# Can't make debounceTime work using http head method in Angular 7

Tags: rxjs, angular7, rxjs6, debouncing

The task is to check that the login is free for use or is already in use by another user. For this I use the HEAD request, when the response comes with **404 status code** means the login is free, if the response comes with **200 status code** means the login is already in use by another user. Every time when I enter a single letter in the input field it makes a request to server and it works, **but I tried to use debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged to wait a second before make request, in order not to send a request after each key press** . And I imported it from RxJS.
 **import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators'**. But it doesn't work for me. The request still comes after each key press. Here it is my html input field. It calls **checkLogin()** on every keyup

```
<input
            pInputText
            placeholder="Login"
            id="float-input-login"
            [(ngModel)]="teacher.login"
            name="login"
            [class.is-invalid]="login.invalid && login.touched"
            #login="ngModel"
            minlength="5"
            maxlength="20"
            (keyup)="checkLogin()"
          />
```

Here it is my component **checkLogin()** method code:

```
checkLogin() {
    this.loginStatus = '';
    if (this.teacher.login.length >= 5) {
      this._teacherServices
        .checkLoginTeacher(this.teacher)
        .pipe(debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged())
        .subscribe(checkResponse => {
          if (
            checkResponse == null &&
            this.selectedTeacher.login !== this.teacher.login
          ) {
            this.loginStatus = 'The login is already in use';
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

End here it is my Service head method:

```
public checkLoginTeacher(teacher: Iteachers): Observable<Iteachers> {
    return this.http
      .head<Iteachers>(`/users/login/${teacher.login}/`)
      .map((response: any) => {
        return response;
      });
  }
```

And Interface:

```
export interface Iteachers {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  patronymic: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  id: number;
  email: string;
  avatar: string;
  login: string;
  phone: string;
  newPass: string;
  oldPass: string;
}
```

Again I want to say that I imported everything what it needs , waiting for your proposals. Thank you!

Comment: You're making a new chain on every `checkLogin` call so you need to use the same approach with intermedite `Subject` as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619503/why-switchmap-does-not-cancel-previous-observer/53619577#53619577. Also check if `401` status code is passed as `next` or `error` item.

Comment: Please, have a look at [Angular formControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl), you need to declare your text input as a `formControl` instance then subscribe to the `valueChanges` Observable property when you `ngInit` your component. This way, you won't create a new chain each time a key is pressed.